# Assigning data-entry tasks to multiple concurrent web-app users

Tags: sql, concurrency, locking

I'm trying to think of an efficient way to allow a group of people to work through a queue of data entry tasks.  Previously we've just had one person doing this so it hasn't been an issue.  The back-end is an RDBMS and the front-end is a web-application.

Currently we do something like this:

To assign a record for editing:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE in_edit_queue LIMIT 1;
```

Then,

To save changes to a previously assigned record:

```
UPDATE records SET ..., in_edit_queue = false
  WHERE id = ? AND in_edit_queue = true;
```

This means it's possible for two users to be assigned the same record to edit, and we favor the first one that submits, failing silently on subsequent submissions, e.g.:

1. User A loads up record 321 for editing
2. User B loads up record 321 for editing
3. User B submits changes (they are saved in the DB)
4. User A submits changes (they are not saved in the DB)

(Note: We can trust all our users to submit acceptable data, so there is no need for us to keep the data from the second `UPDATE`.)

The problem with this method is when users start at the same time and edit at roughly the same speed, they are often updating the same records but only 1 of them is getting saved.  In other words, wasting a lot of man-hours.  I can mitigate this to some extent by picking random rows but I'd prefer something a bit more guaranteed.

So here's what I'm thinking...

Have a table called: `locked_records (record_id integer, locked_until timestamp)`

```
-- Assign a record for editing:
-- Same as before but also make sure the
-- record is not listed in locked_records...
SELECT * FROM records
  WHERE in_edit_queue AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT record_id FROM locked_records
    WHERE locked_until > now() )
  LIMIT 1;

-- ..and effectively remove it from
-- the queue for the next 5 minutes
INSERT INTO locked_records (record_id, locked_until)
  VALUES (?, now() + 300);
```

Then:

```
UPDATE records SET ..., in_edit_queue = false
  WHERE id = ? AND in_edit_queue = true;
DELETE FROM locked_records WHERE record_id = ?;
```

A typical edit takes about 30 seconds to 1 minute, 5 minutes out of the queue should be a good amount.  I can also have an XHR on the web app keep updating the lock if it turned out to be advantageous.

Can anyone offer thoughts on this?  Sound like a good way of doing things?  Sound like a terrible way?  Done this before?  I'd love to hear some feedback.

Thanks!
J

Answer (score 0):

What about the RDBMSes internal list of locks?  Would altering the SELECT statement to be SELECT FOR UPDATE be an option?

Comment: I don't think so, since the UPDATE will occur through a different database connection as it's a web app.  Or not at all, as again.. it is a web app :-)  If I'm misunderstanding something please let me know...

Comment: p.s. If you meant as an alternative to maintaining a separate locked_records table then yes I think that would work and be more elegant but the 'records' table is constantly being read-from quite heavily by non-editing users and I don't want to lock it for that reason.

Comment: The possibility that a different DB connection might be used would have to be evaluated; you're right that a SELECT FOR UPDATE wont work in that scenario.

A SELECT FOR UPDATE shouldn't prevent access by readers in most RDBMSes, you'd have to check the docos for your one.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea: these records have two additional columns: assigned_to and completed.

When someone wants to edit a record, do something like

```
update records set assigned_to = ? # assigning to 'me'
where assigned_to is null
and completed = false
limit 1 # only assign one record at a time
```

Then, to get that row back:

```
select ...
from records
where assigned_to = ? # assigned to 'me'
and completed = false
```

And once you're done you set the completed to 'true'.

You could have an additional timestamp column for when a record was assigned to someone, and then add an OR alternative to the "assigned_to is null" part of the where clause in the update statement above, where you require a certain recensy for an assignment to be valid.